# Center and contain menu div

Tags: html, css

I'm building a hover menu using css and bootstrap(for flex grid). If I try to put my menu in any parent div, my menu only goes as wide as the parent div.

Also I can't seem to center my hover menu to the length of my menu item.

So, how can I make my menu items stretch the width so the text does not wrap onto a new line and how do I center the whole menu relevant to it's link?

html

```
  <div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Small</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1 long link</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Long Menu item</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1 long link</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">a really long Long Menu item</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1 long link</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    /* Dropdown Button */
    .dropbtn {
        color: #3a3a3a;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
       border: none;
  }

  /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
  .dropdown {
      position: relative;
  }

  /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    color:#3a3a3a;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


.dropdown-content:after, .dropdown-content:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown-content:after {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 13px;
    margin-left: -13px;
}
.dropdown-content:before {
    border-bottom-color: #cecece;
    border-width: 14px;
    margin-left: -14px;
}




/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
   color:$green;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    //background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

Comment: I'm not totally sure your JSFiddle link is working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I make my menu items stretch the width so the text does not wrap onto a new line?

You can use the css property `white-space: nowrap;`, so Text will never wrap to the next line. See docs: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp

> new line and how do I center the whole menu relevant to it's link?

So you can set a position `left:50%` and then use the `transform` property setting the value translateX(50%) to bring it back 50% of its size. Add the following to `.dropdown-content` :

```
left: 50%;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

```css
/* Dropdown Button */
    .dropbtn {
        color: #3a3a3a;
        padding: 16px;
        font-size: 16px;
       border: none;
  }

  /* The container <div> - needed to position the dropdown content */
  .dropdown {
      position: relative;
  }

  /* Dropdown Content (Hidden by Default) */
  .dropdown-content {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #cecece;
    color:#3a3a3a;
    z-index: 1;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}


.dropdown-content:after, .dropdown-content:before {
    bottom: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none;
}

.dropdown-content:after {
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-width: 13px;
    margin-left: -13px;
}
.dropdown-content:before {
    border-bottom-color: #cecece;
    border-width: 14px;
    margin-left: -14px;
}




/* Links inside the dropdown */
.dropdown-content a {
    color: black;
    padding: 12px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

/* Change color of dropdown links on hover */
.dropdown-content a:hover {
   color:$green;
}

/* Show the dropdown menu on hover */
.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
    display: block;
}

/* Change the background color of the dropdown button when the dropdown content is shown */
.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
    //background-color: #3e8e41;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="d-flex flex-row">
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Small</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1 long link</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">Long Menu item</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1 long link</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="dropbtn">a really long Long Menu item</button>
    <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1 long link</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```